# replace url if word start with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I want to replace the url if a word starts with **getlink**.

```
  download file: xxxxxxxxxx.com 

  getlink file:  xxxxxxxxxx.com
```

**Only replace xxxxxxxxxx.com to mmmmmmmm111.com**

How can I do that using JavaScript?

Comment: Please share your attempt and describe the issue that you facing.

Comment: @gurvinder372 i don't want to replace multiple links manually

Comment: Please be more specific and clear regarding the issue you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use window.location.href to get the url of the current page.

Inside of your javascript code just have some code that looks like this

```
if (window.location.href == "xxxxxxx.com") {
   location = "mmmmmmmmmm111.com"
}
```

It would be a bg help if you could be more specific and include some more detailed explanations and code.

Comment: He wants to replace only when some word (which the asker don't show how he gets it) starts with "getlink" not every `location.href`

Comment: Ok didn't realize that.